# Finding next few element usings the current WebElement object in Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I need to get values from adjacent cells in the row to the current cell. The current cells are every cell in column 1 where the title begins with `BC_`. In HTML the cells are represented using div blocks. I need to get adjacent cells in that row and store them in WebElements div1, div2, div3 etc. Then repeat the same for each row. And print out text contents of each.

I tried using the recommended function, but it didn't work, it gets the first element correctly but not the adjacent one.

My edited code is below, it works, but it seems to grab every row and store it in `div1` not sure why

```
        myElems = browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[title^='BC_']"
        with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
            for webElement in myElems :
                f.write(webElement.text)
                print(webElement.text)                
                div1=browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//following-sibling::div")  
                print(div1.text) 
                f.write(div1.text + "\r\n") 
                print('')
```

The problem is that I don't have the XPath of the current WebElement. I don't know where it is looking for using `//div/following-sibling::div`
Does it actually use the current element's XPath if I use `//` or do I need to enter the full `"[title^='BC_']//div/following-sibling::div"`. In this case, how would I be sure it selects the correct row, and not just the first row over and over.

Is it possible to get the XPath of current WebElement and append it to the XPath in `find_element` with `following-sibling::div`?

How can I modify the code to get the next couple WebElements from the current on in the `for` loop?

Small section of HTML table is below:

```
<div title="BC_Compliance" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="2" tabindex="0" class="pivotTableCellWrap cell-interactive " style="padding-top:1px;padding-right:5px;padding-bottom:1px;padding-left:5px;color:#252423;background-color:#FFFFFF;--outline-top:1px;--outline-right:1px;--outline-bottom:1px;--outline-left:1px;position:absolute;box-sizing:border-box;height:100%;width:138.41970520753088px;left:0;--padding-left:5px;--padding-right:5px;">BC_Compliance</div>
<div title="E534565P" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="3" tabindex="0" class="pivotTableCellWrap cell-interactive " style="padding-top:1px;padding-right:5px;padding-bottom:1px;padding-left:5px;color:#252423;background-color:#FFFFFF;--outline-top:1px;--outline-right:1px;--outline-bottom:1px;--outline-left:1px;position:absolute;box-sizing:border-box;height:100%;width:133.80964889015144px;left:138.41970520753088px;--padding-left:5px;--padding-right:5px;">E534565P</div>
<div title="C5645F" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="4" tabindex="0" class="pivotTableCellWrap cell-interactive " style="padding-top:1px;padding-right:5px;padding-bottom:1px;padding-left:5px;color:#252423;background-color:#FFFFFF;--outline-top:1px;--outline-right:1px;--outline-bottom:1px;--outline-left:1px;position:absolute;box-sizing:border-box;height:100%;width:125.80502424070256px;left:272.2293540976823px;--padding-left:5px;--padding-right:5px;">C5645F</div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you confirm the url, if it's publicly accessible? If not, can you post the page HTML, as well as a clear example of what you want as end -product?

Comment: Please post the relevant html and your expected output from the html

Comment: It is not publically available or shareable on SO, but I can post a portion of it